# iOS Xcode Objective-C documenting not in .h file

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm not asking for a tool as HeaderDoc, Doxygen, appledoc, ....

I'm asking for a way that documenting a method not in .h file.

I MEAN: I don't want to documenting in .h file.

I know we can document that method on .m file at the same method. Too much lines in .h file make the file not easy tracking when some one see the file, so I move docs to .m file.

But there's a case when I need to write document for method in @protocol. It's .h file, has no .m file. And I don't want to document in .h file for easy tracking when some one see the file.

I see iOS sdk has a case for that. As you can inspect built-in @protocol UITableViewDataSource, the documenting is not place in the declaration, it is placed somewhere.

Do you know the way? Thank you.

Comment: Documentation is not bound to any file! You can easily use it in a header, implementation or protocol! See this link for more http://www.raywenderlich.com/66395/documenting-in-xcode-with-headerdoc-tutorial

Comment: @Alexander The problem is that I don't want to documenting in .h file. So I need to place somewhere that it still work when I do quick docs (Option + Command). With methods in \@interface, it's OK to place docs in .m. But with methods in \@protocol, it's no .m file.

Comment: Why don't you want the documentation in the header file? If it's visible to other parts of the app, then I fail to see what the problem is with having it documented?

Comment: @Anorak The docs is still visible when you do quick docs (Option+Command) or generate docs. That the way iOS SDK is implementing. With methods in \@interface, docs is written in .m file at the same method. But with methods in \@protocol, I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation can be easily added to any method, property etc. no matter if declared in a header, a protocol or a .m file!

See my example below:

```
/**
 * Request calendar access.
 * @param access granted block – the block to perform if access has been granted
 */
- (void) requestCalendarAccess:(void (^) (void)) accessGrantedBlock;
```

More info about easy documentation is available here: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/66395/documenting-in-xcode-with-headerdoc-tutorial

Comment: Sorry, The problem is that I don't want to documenting in .h file. I want to place docs in somewhere not .h file. With methods in \@interface, it's OK to place in .m file. But with methods in \@protocol, there's no .m file

Comment: Honestly I do not exactly understand where you want to place you documentation? If you do not have a m-file, you have to document it in the header - IMHO there is no other option. You say " I want to place docs in somewhere not .h ". What is somewhere? Word? Website? txt-File?

Comment: Somewhere is a way by Xcode. You see 'UITableViewDataSource' don't place docs in header file.